# Codeigniter update database with current data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to develop a function that update table row with current data in `Codeigniter`.

**For example**,

```
Table: `api_keys`
--------------------------------------------------
           Column    |      Value
--------------------------------------------------
row 1 -> | key_data  |    key is generated success 
---------------------------------------------------
```

I need to update this row `key_data` with `now you can use it`, such that

```
Table: `api_keys`
------------------------------------------------------------------------
           Column    |      Value
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
row 1 -> | key_data  |    key is generated success now you can use it 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried with `insert_string`, but it's error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you please update the error details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this idea:

```
UPDATE YourTable
    SET YourColumn = YourColumn + 'Appended Data'
```

It would be something like:

```
UPDATE `api_keys`
        SET `key_data` = `key_data` + ' now you can use it'
```

**PLEASE NOTE**: Do not forgot to put `WHERE` clause on `UPDATE` or keep a copy of current data/table with you.

Comment: @Rade does this helpful